# InvalidUseOfMatchersException when stubbing a method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

For a mock of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

```
@Mock
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
```

I tried to stub it as follows:

```
doReturn(1L).when(template).queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(MapSqlParameterSource.class), Long.class);
```

and got this error:

```
 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
 Invalid use of argument matchers!
 3 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
 -> at com.bns.tds.api.mortgage.points.fulfillment.repository.dao.PointsIssuanceReconDaoTest.insertPointsIssuanceReconEntryNoProfile(PointsIssuanceReconDaoTest.java:59)
 -> at com.bns.tds.api.mortgage.points.fulfillment.repository.dao.PointsIssuanceReconDaoTest.insertPointsIssuanceReconEntryNoProfile(PointsIssuanceReconDaoTest.java:59)

 This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
     //incorrect:
     someMethod(any(), "raw String");
 When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
 For example:
     //correct:
     someMethod(any(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

What did I get wrong?